# charge on the capacitors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-current, capacitance

When we connecting a capacitor to a battery of $V$ volts. After it is completely charged, it is disconnected from the battery, and if we connected to another capacitor. In this case, there is no battery, but there is charged capacitor which is first capacitor. If we connect another capacitor to first capacitor, how the current flow? What is the direction of current flow? How can deal with it? And I think that after disconnect battery and connect to second capacitor, charges on the first capacitor will be shared with second capacitor? Is it true? If not, how is charged the second capacitor?

Answer (score 1):

Electrons will flow from the negative plate of the charged capacitor onto one of the plates of the initially uncharged capacitor.
At the same time electrons will also flow from the other plate of the initially uncharged capacitor onto the positive plate of the charged capacitor.
So the charged capacitor is losing charge to charge the initially uncharged capacitor.
This will continue until the voltage across both capacitors is the same.